# Rank NULL Value as well while using Rank in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a newbie and learning SQL. While practising SQL on a practise platform, I came across the below question :
Write a SQL query to get the second highest salary from the Employee table.

```
|Id  | Salary 
| 1  | 100   
| 2  | 200 
| 3  | 300
```

For example, given the above Employee table, the query should return 200 as the second highest salary. If there is no second highest salary, then the query should return null.

> | SecondHighestSalary | | 200                 |

I intend to use Oracle Analytical function to write the query. The query I have written is as below :

```
select Salary as SecondHighestSalary 
from (SELECT salary, dense_rank() over(order by salary desc)  myrank 
FROM Employee)
where myrank =2;
```

My query is not able to handle the NULL values test case and throws me error. Can anyone answer my question?

Comment: what error message did you get?

Comment: What is the definition of "there is no second-highest salary"? I understand if there is only one salary (in the entire data) there is no second-highest; are there any other cases?

Comment: @ZekiGumus : Incase of the test case with value null, my query fails to display value as null . Error shown is as below :

Input
{"headers": {"Employee": ["Id", "Salary"]}, "rows": {"Employee": [[1, 100]]}}
Output
{"headers":["SECONDHIGHESTSALARY"],"values":[]}
Expected
{"headers":["SecondHighestSalary"],"values":[[null]]}

Comment: I just took your data and your query and [created a dbfiddle with it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0e0d397099508d58f349e97575c1815e). When all three rows are available the query correctly returns 200. When only one row is available the query returns nothing, as it should. When no rows are available, again, the query returns nothing. Please edit your question using the `edit` button just below the tags and tell us what error message you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis This is a question from LeetCode practise questions. So I simply pasted the question from there to here.

Comment: @BobJarvis : Thank you for checking this in fiddle.
 My question is resolved by Gordon.

Answer (score 2):

You query is returning *no rows* when there is no second highest value.  If you want a single row with `NULL`, you need to make that happen.  A simple method would be an aggregation function:

```
select max(Salary) as SecondHighestSalary 
from (SELECT salary, dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) as myrank 
      from Employee
     ) e
where myrank = 2;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,
Thank you for your response. This works best. Thank you very much.
I have written another query with similar concept of displaying ro with NULL Value, as below :

select max(Salary) as SecondHighestSalary 
FROM
(
select salary, nvl(DENSE_RANK() OVER(order by salary desc), null) as nth FROM Employee
) 
where nth = 2;

Comment: `DENSE_RANK()` can never return `NULL`, so I'm not sure what `nvl()` is supposed to be doing (and I recommend `COALESCE()` because it is the ANSI/ISO standard function).

Comment: Hi Gordon, 

Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will work as well. Both `min(Salary)` and `max(Salary)` will work.

```
SELECT min(Salary) as "SecondHighestSalary" FROM (
    SELECT Salary, dense_rank() over(ORDER BY Salary DESC) as dense_rank
    from Employee
    ) WHERE dense_rank=2;
```